# Can not install steam: E: Unable to locate package

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, steam

I've  ran `update` and `upgrade` and are working fine. But when I try
`sudo apt-get install steam` all i get is

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package steam
```

I'm using KDE. I've troubleshooted a lot of things and i cant figure it out

Answer (score 1):

`Steam` is in multiverse repository, so you have to enable it before installing `steam`.

Open Software center, navigate to the "Ubuntu software" tab at the top, select (check off) multiverse.

[image]

Use the "Reload" button to update your package list.

Now, install with `sudo apt-get install steam`.

Comment: i did what you said but when i press on the box beside it it just blinks an doesn't turn off or take the check off it stays there

Comment: @Jake61 When you click the box, you should get a pop-up window where you have to enter your root password and hit 'Authenticate`. After that you can click 'Close' which will give you another pop-up windows where you can hit "Reload' to generate your sources list.

Comment: How do I enable it with terminal instead of UI?